# DevExpress Winforms: TextEdit with SpellChecker - Misspelled word wavy underline not rendering correctly

Tags: winforms, devexpress

When I implement a spellchecker component in a TextEdit, the line beneath misspelled words is straight rather than wavy, as I have it set in the settings. Am I missing something? Things work fine in my MemoEdit controls. It almost looks as though there isn't enough room at the bottom of the TextEdit to fit a wavy line, but it seems like something DevExpress wouldn't have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this following link might help you:

> https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4831
>
> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B201020

Comment: Thanks--the second link answered my question. Don't know how I missed it while searching for an answer. Bummer, though.

Comment: That's why we have this community to help each other to solve issues :) :)

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this: I ended up modifying the MemoEdit control to accept only one line (by handling its KeyPress and EditValueChanged events) and set the MemoEdit's height to that of a TextEdit using the same font as the MemoEdit. This gave me the behavior I want.